# Exception while running flutter application. Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, flutter

We got an exception while running Flutter application in android studio 3.2.1. The error that occurred is given below. Please check and help us. I tried some solutions which were available on stackoverflow and other sites as well.

But unfortunately any of the provided solutions didn't work for me. I even did invalidate caches/restart my android studio. The problem was still occurring.

```
Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:

Launching lib\main.dart on Moto G 5S Plus in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
--------- beginning of main
11-22 16:03:41.480 I/Icing   ( 3057): Indexing done com.google.android.gms-contacts_contact_id
Unhandled exception:
Exit code -1073740940 from: D:/Android/sdk\platform-tools\adb -s ZY3227B4JT shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
#0      _runWithLoggingSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:353:7)
#1      runCheckedSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:284:10)
#2      AndroidDevice.lastLogcatTimestamp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:504:27)
#3      _AdbLogReader._start (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:678:41)
#4      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:804:24)
#5      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:217:7)
#6      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:817:19)
#7      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:472:9)
#8      FlutterDevice.startEchoingDeviceLog (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:242:71)
#9      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:285:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:272:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     AppDomain.startApp.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:387:62)
#12     AppDomain.launch.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:438:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     AppInstance._runInZone (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:820:20)
#20     AppDomain.launch (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:436:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#21     AppDomain.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:384:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:289:38)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:401:18)
#24     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#25     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#26     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#27     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#28     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#29     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#30     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#31     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#32     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:28:18)
#33     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:295:13)
#34     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#35     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#36     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#37     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#38     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#39     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#40     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#41     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#42     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#43     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#44     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#45     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#46     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#47     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#48     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#49     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#50     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just able to get Flutter working on my computer after experiencing the same error message by adjusting the security mitigations in Windows Defender.

It seems like ADB wasn't executing properly and some playing around with settings and which applications they applied to resulted in the following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Go to "Exploit Protection": **Windows Security** > **App & browser control** > **Exploit Protection** > **Program Settings**
2. Click on **Add program to customize** and select **Choose exact file path**
3. Select your **`adb.exe`** executable which in my case was `C:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe`
4. Scroll to the **"Validate heap integrity"** section and make sure the checkbox for **Override system settings** is checked, and the switch is in the **Off** position

Answer (score 1):

There's a temporary fix where you can follow the steps provided in this link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33938#issuecomment-499250288

> I found a temporary fix while we wait for a solution provided by the Flutter team
>
> Windows: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip
>
> macOS: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-darwin.zip
>
> Linux: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-linux.zip

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing **Android SDK Platform-Tools**.

Open Android Studio -> Configure (bottom right) -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools (2nd Tap)

[image]