# Flutter error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi

Tags: android, flutter, unhandled-exception

I am new to flutter and have successfully gotten it installed and working on one machine, but when working on this one I am having some issues. It is a fresh install of android studio, flutter, and gradle. The machine is running an updated Windows 10.

The Flutter doctor statement returns an error while retrieving device properties.

```
C:\Development\FlutterApps\first_app>flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.523], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at C:\Development\Flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (8 weeks ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

\Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:
                                                                                                                                                                                       [
√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Development\Android
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Development\Android
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 31.3.3
    • Dart plugin version 182.5124
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-arm • Android null (API null)

• No issues found!
```

When trying to run the flutter app on an emulated android instance or a real device I get the same error:

```
Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
--------- beginning of system
01-22 22:51:04.010 E/BatteryStatsService( 1698): modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
Unhandled exception:
Exit code -1073740940 from: C:/Development/Android\platform-tools\adb -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
#0      _runWithLoggingSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:353:7)
#1      runCheckedSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:284:10)
#2      AndroidDevice.lastLogcatTimestamp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:504:27)
#3      _AdbLogReader._start (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:678:41)
#4      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:804:24)
#5      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:217:7)
#6      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:817:19)
#7      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:472:9)
#8      FlutterDevice.startEchoingDeviceLog (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:242:71)
#9      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:285:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:272:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     AppDomain.startApp.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:387:62)
#12     AppDomain.launch.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:438:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     AppInstance._runInZone (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:820:20)
#20     AppDomain.launch (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:436:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#21     AppDomain.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:384:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:289:38)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:401:18)
#24     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#25     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#26     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#27     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#28     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#29     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#30     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#31     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#32     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:28:18)
#33     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:295:13)
#34     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#35     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#36     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#37     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#38     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#39     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#40     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#41     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#42     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#43     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#44     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#45     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#46     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#47     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#48     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#49     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#50     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after struggling to get the program working and some more searching, I found a solution to the two issues I was having.

The first issues is android studio would not run unless studio.bat was running, this was fixed by disabling ASLR in windows security settings. (studio.exe/studio64.exe)

The second issue was it could not retrieve device properties, this was fixed by disabling heap protection on adb. (adb.exe)

Post with more details on how to do so:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54164463/4125133

Comment: btw don't disable ASLR completely - it's a security setting. you can disable it just for android studio. as for the second point -damn i would never have thought of that - i disable all antivirus software on my dev machine by default

Answer (score 34):

Another mistake possible is that for a physical device you need to have the **file transfer mode enabled** (not charging) as well as **debugging enabled**.

Answer (score 11):

Try restarting adb, it's a known [issue with the adb daemon service and flutter which you can see on github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10330). it has to be fixed on android side sadly no resolution for near future.

on windows,in administrative mode command prompt/powershell

```
adb kill-server
```

and then

```
adb start-server
```

if adb is not on path in command line you need to add it or navigate to adb.exe location in windows and run command line/powershell from that path.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck restarting adb. Although I am having issues running android studio, none of the .exes will run (The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b)), but running studio.bat in the /Android Studio/Bin works. But because none of the executable files work I cannot uninstall it, any idea what would cause that? And would that be a related issue?

Comment: have you upgraded windows recently? as in go from win7/8 to win10? have you gotten a huge windows update recently? (0x000007b) usually means corrupted windows install

Comment: No version transitions, its a relatively new install with very little on it. It is a laptop with a 4k screen which has caused issues with quite a few programs refusing to scale properly though and sometimes installs will fail because of that. I'm going to attempt to uninstall it, though the uninstaller is broken, and reinstall

Comment: This issue has been fixed, it's a problem where the installed sdk versions are different

Comment: I suggest to use more markups. For example, sentences end with a point.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. I resolved it by changing the USB preferences.
Changing the USB preference from Charging to file transfer worked for me.

Comment: This is what worked for me

Answer (score 1):

There is a temporary fix you can found in this link https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33938#issuecomment-499250288. It worked for me.

P.D. Maybe you need to downgrade from API 29 to API 28 in your Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing **Android SDK Platform-Tools**.

Open Android Studio -> Configure (bottom right) -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools (2nd Tap)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Downgrade Your platform-tools from 29 to 28 use these links.**

### This is a temporary solution only.

Windows: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip

macOS: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-darwin.zip

Linux: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-linux.zip

Source : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33938

**This issue was resolved in a later SDK update.**

Comment: I did not want to go for this option..but somehow, downgrading worked for me! This should be a temporary solutions ofcourseThanks

Comment: @Prachi yes, of course, its a temporary solution flutter team will provide a permanent solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

cmd on flutter folder:
_git pull
_flutter channel master
_ and flutter doctor

this solve all my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Up to this date, the only way I was able to solve this problem was downgrading to 
**Android Platform Tools 28** from http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip

Used the .zip to completely replace the contents of the **platform-tools** folder located at

C:\Users\[*my-username*]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\

(Bear in mind that the **AppData** subfolder is hidden).

After that, flutter doctor did not find any issues and I was able to deploy the App in my Android device.

Ref. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33938

Answer (score 0):

I also have problem i reinstall hole system but problem is still so **to solve the problem following steps** to be follow:

1. Windows: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip
   macOS: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-darwin.zip
   Linux: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-linux.zip
2. After downloading past in sdk path and replace to your platform-tools
3. Restart your computer
4. After restart you open Android studio there is update for **platform-tool don't update 
   ignore** it then run app you done

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem and I tried many solutions at the end this one worked for me.

**Windows**

> Just open  **Task Manger** and you will find  progress named
> `adb.exe` just end the task and run `flutter doctor -v` and its good
> to go.

After that in Visual studio Code on Run is terminated with this error

> Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
> Performing Streamed Install
> adb: failed to install  ~\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk:
> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Package couldn't be installed in
> /data/app/com.example.weather_flutter-Azzrb6hHi67p7xfzCG6lyA==:
> Package
> /data/app/com.example.weather_flutter-Azzrb6hHi67p7xfzCG6lyA==/base.apk
> code is missing] Error launching application on SM A105F.

Just clean the  build directorie using command  `flutter clean`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this after I rooted my phone. What solved it for me was simply disabling and re-enabling the option USB debugging from the 'Developer options' menu

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by changing the USB Pregerence from file transfer to charging.In case it does not work open the task manager in windows and find the process names adb.

Just end the task and run flutter doctor -v and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem but I just started the adb server
under linux $ {HOME}/Android/Sdk/platform-tools server/adb start-server