# I setup android studio, flutter, etc on a new laptop running Window 10. but it is not working Following is the Log :

Tags: android, mobile, flutter

Flutter Doctor 
Output

```
 C:\Users\username>flutter doctor
   Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
   [√] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.3.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.590],               locale en-US)
   \ Checking Android licenses is taking an unexpectedly long time...****Error        retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:****
   [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
   [√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
   [√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.32.1)
   [√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

You can see here Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi: Error and my device is connected with Andriod studio.

```
Following the Error from Android studio :

Error retrieving device properties for ro.hardware:

Launching lib\main.dart on ONEPLUS in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
--------- beginning of main
03-10 18:14:09.910 D/vendor.qti.bluetooth@1.0-wake_lock(  691): Release wakelock is released
Unhandled exception:
Exit code -1073740940 from: D:/Mobile-Dev/src/Andriod/SDK\platform-tools\adb -s 5df11745 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
#0      _runWithLoggingSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:352:7)
#1      runCheckedSync (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart:283:10)
#2      AndroidDevice.lastLogcatTimestamp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:507:27)
#3      _AdbLogReader._start (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:681:41)
#4      _runGuarded (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:805:24)
#5      _BroadcastStreamController._subscribe (dart:async/broadcast_stream_controller.dart:213:7)
#6      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:818:19)
#7      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:472:9)
#8      FlutterDevice.startEchoingDeviceLog (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:261:71)
#9      FlutterDevice.runHot (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:304:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     HotRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_hot.dart:295:39)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     AppDomain.startApp.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:393:23)
#12     AppDomain.launch.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:452:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142:29)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1516:10)
#17     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1463:12)
#18     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#19     AppInstance._runInZone (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:835:20)
#20     AppDomain.launch (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:450:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#21     AppDomain.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:387:12)
<asynchronous suspension>
#22     RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:281:38)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:545:18)
#24     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#25     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#26     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#27     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#28     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#29     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#30     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#31     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#32     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:28:18)
#33     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:294:13)
#34     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
#35     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#36     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#37     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#38     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#39     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#40     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#41     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#42     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#43     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:28:18)
#44     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:294:13)
#45     AndroidDevice.targetPlatform (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart)
#46     _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#47     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#48     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#49     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:126:18)
#50     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:639:45)
#51     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:32)
#52     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:473:7)
#53     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#54     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#55     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#56     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#57     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#58     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#59     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#60     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#61     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

Comment: Please check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10330. This is a known android bug.

Comment: This error occurs when there are a adb daemon.

type: ps -axxx | grep adb
than kill the proccess and try gain

Comment: when i am running through CLI with flutter run command 
   D:\Mobile-Dev\src\flutter\examples\hello_world>flutter run
   Running "flutter packages get" in hello_world...                    2.9s
   Error retrieving device properties for ro.hardware:

   Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode...
   Initializing gradle...                                              3.2s  
  Resolving dependencies...                                          27.4s
  rest is the same error

Comment: adb kill-server and adb start-server is not resolving my problem.

Comment: @punit i am working on windows 10. and i am not sure this ps will work or not

Comment: @vishva adb kill-server and adb start-server on windows

Comment: @kkarakk already done it. but nothing is happening. Always getting the same error Error retrieving device properties for ro.hardware:

Answer (score 0):

```
This problem is related with ro.hardware or adb server couldn't get access on 
 Emulator or Mobile devices. 
Now you can follow the bellow instruction : 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429152/exception-while-running-flutter-
```

application-error-retrieving-device-properties/54164463#54164463][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429152/exception-while-running-flutter-application-error-retrieving-device-properties/54164463#54164463)

For me this was the solution.

Thank you for your support and reading